# ¿Porcentaje de uso de CPU limitada para Java?

Tags: java, exe

Acabo de generar el ejecutable (.exe) de una aplicación que hice en Java. El problema es que en el administrador de tareas me muestra un porcentaje de uso de la CPU siempre menor al 30%.

¿Este porcentaje se puede incrementar?

¿Como modifico el icono que aparece en la barra de tareas al ejecutar la aplicación?

Comment: muy probablemente ese porcentaje corresponda a un nucleo de tu CPU, para ocupar mas tendrías que utilizar mas hilos.